# Inject or Add a custom stage to a shared library pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

```
@Library(["global-library"]) _
 
pipeline_sharedBuild2019([
    path: "Internal.sln",
    buildOutput: "./bin",
    npm: "true",
    nodeVersion: '18.x'
])
```

I'm using a shared Jenkins pipeline to run my build. Is there a way that I can inject/add a stage to this pipeline?

Comment: Depend on your library. Does pipeline_sharedBuild2019's call method have a second parameter of type Closure?

Comment: No it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with the shared library, it's totally possible, all you need is to define your stage in your library (`vars` preferably if you have not worked with `src`).

Then you call the `.groovy` file containing your stage, from your pipeline.